# Annoying notification of updating mac os x Mojave

Tags: macos, notifications, macos-mojave

I am using MacBook Pro with mac os x Mojave. Having a lot of 32bit applications, I don't want to update Catalina but having the annoying notification. I have unchecked software update still it showing. Is there any way how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/`
2. Delete (drag the file to the trash) the following files: `com.apple.softwareupdate.plist`, `com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.plist` (if you have them both)
3. Reboot normally
4. If the notification is still there try
5. Going into `Software Preferences > Software Update`, it said the same `"Your Mac is up to date -- macOS Catalina 10.15.4"` and then the badge should disappear!
6. Automatic updates are still enabled and the badge should not come back.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstored LastUpdateNotification -date "2029-12-12 12:00:00 +0000"
```

It hides the notification until the end of 2029. You can use any future date here.